# Android default code error

Tags: android, netbeans-7

I am new to android development I have installed SDK in netbeans 7.1.1 .
This is the default code which gets generated when i create a new android project in netbeans

```
package android.bug;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
  }
}
```

Default code should be free from errors but i am getting an error in the last line i.e "setContentView(R.layout.main)"

```
 error is : package R does not exist
```

But when i import R package in the above code then i get a different error in the same line i.e "setContentView(R.layout.main)"

```
 error :cannot find symbol : main
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may have some errors in your `res` folder.

`R.java` is auto generated file. It wont create until you solve all your errors from `res` folder.

for example: error in `main.xml`

solve all errors, clean your project and

```
import yourpackagename.R;
```

see [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11467781/1289716) problem

Comment: This answer is good. It's a common error you may encounter during android app development.

Comment: are you able to find `R.java` in your project ?

Comment: @gtumca-MAC how to get R.java file ??

Answer (score 0):

I specified the android SDK folder in eclipse (Window - Preferences, Android SDK Location) without a trailing \ . So the path to aapt.exe tool was wrong (C:\android-sdk-windowsplatform-tools instead of C:\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools) and the resources not built.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at this question, it's pretty comprehensive for issues with R files: [R cannot be resolved - Android error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885009/r-cannot-be-resolved-android-error)

Also, [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-classic-42/junor) is the recommended IDE for Android development, you may want to try it.